# How to create feature type from xml attribute value?

Tags: fme-form, xml

Here is a sample from an xml child element:

```
<element>
<aspects>
<a id="1" l="de" v="Grundlose Kuhle"/>
<a id="2" p="6" code="7"/>
<a id="3" p="12" code="6"/>
<a id="5" v="2925/005-0"/>
<a id="39" l="de" v="siehe Medien"/>
</aspects>
<aspects>
<a id="1" l="de" v="another value"/>
<a id="2" p="6" code="4"/>
<a id="3" p="12" code="2"/>
<a id="5" v="2925/005-0"/>
<a id="39" l="de" v="another value"/>
</aspects>
</element>
```

I want to extract the value "Grundlose Kuhle" from the aspects.a.id="1".v element.

How can I get FME to put all "v"-values from ID="1" elements into a list so that I can write them to a featuretype?

Comment: XQueryExtractor http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/xqueryextractor.htm will do this Example/Workspaces http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/How-to-Use-XQuery-Expressions-to-Query-XML-Data-Within-FME